# Why is it "a six on two consecutive rolls" rather than "two sixes"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

I got stuck by this sentence:

> What is the probability of rolling a six on two consecutive rolls of a
>   fair six-sided die?

I thought it would just be a binomial random variable problem, where only one occurrence of six would be OK, but found that it is asking for a joint probability which means that both two rolls should show six.

Why does "a six on two consecutive rolls" mean two sixes rather than one(a)?

Comment: Because you are talking about single action (rolling a six) that occurs on more than one occasion. Contrast that with a situation if you had two dice: "What is the probability of rolling two sixes on consecutive rolls?"

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: **Consecutive** means "*one after the other*."

In general we can say that

> Outcome X happened Y consecutive times

means that, when doing a repeating action, the outcome was X the first time, then it was repeated and the outcome was again X, then again X, etc. And this happened Y times in a row without any other outcome happening in between.

We can thus rewrite your sentence as

> What is the probability that, when rolling a fair six-sided die twice, we get a roll of 6 both times?

Comment: It would have been clearer if the sentence had been written with "consecutive" modifying "six**es**" instead of "rolls".